# Observable.Using { WebSocket.ReceiveAsync(); } aborts and cancels early

Tags: c#, .net, websocket, async-await, system.reactive

In the code below, the `Connect()` appears to work fine. However `webSocket.ReceiveAsync()` in `ReceiveMessage()` seems to set `cancelToken.IsCancellationRequested = true` and `webSocket.State = Aborted` the moment the server doesn't have anything to offer. At the same time, the same `ReceiveAsync()` call raises an (unhelpful) `OperationCanceledException`, with no inner exception.

I've engaged the same server using what I thought was the same WebSocket interaction without this problem, but with simpler async code. It wasn't until I tried converting it to an observable that I had this problem.

Does it get cancelled by Rx, or does it cancel itself? I found a mention of such a thing being caused in .NET WebSockets by unobserved exceptions (http://www.salmanq.com/blog/5-things-you-probably-didnt-know-about-net-websockets/2013/04/), but I couldn't find any evidence of this occurring after adding `TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += ExceptionLogger`.

Any ideas?

```
public static IObservable<string> GetWebSocketStream(Uri uri)
{
    var buffer = new byte[2048];
    return Observable
        .Using(cancelToken => Connect(uri, cancelToken),
            (webSocket, cancelToken) => Task.FromResult(
                Observable.Defer(
                    () => ReceiveMessage(webSocket, buffer, cancelToken).ToObservable()
                ).Repeat()
            )
        ).Publish().RefCount();
}

private static async Task<ClientWebSocket> Connect(Uri uri, CancellationToken token)
{
    var webSocket = new ClientWebSocket();
    await webSocket.ConnectAsync(uri, token).ConfigureAwait(false);
    return webSocket;
}

private static async Task<string> ReceiveMessage(ClientWebSocket webSocket, byte[] buffer, CancellationToken cancelToken)
{
    var segment = new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer);
    var message = new StringBuilder();
    WebSocketReceiveResult result;
    do
    {
        result = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(segment, cancelToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
        message.Append(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(segment.Array, 0, result.Count));
    } while (!cancelToken.IsCancellationRequested && !result.EndOfMessage);
    return message.ToString();
}
```

---

**EDIT:** To clarify, my question/problem is probably related to BOTH WebSockets AND Rx. The similar code below, on the same device, remains open and receives data:

```
public static void Test() {
    var ts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    AsyncTest(new Uri("ws://server/test/"), ts.Token).Wait();
}

public static async Task AsyncTest(Uri uri, CancellationToken token) {
    var socket = await GetConnectedWebSocket(uri, token);
    var buffer = new byte[4000];
    while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        try
        {
            var msg = await ReceiveMessage(socket, buffer, token);
            Debug.WriteLine(msg);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You will get an exception if the string returns null.  So simply add an exception handler or test for null.

Comment: @jdweng: Where would I catch or test? The exception is raised by `await ReceiveAsync()`, and the exception is `OperationCanceledException` with no inner exception. At that time the `cancelToken` is already set and the `webSocket` is already aborted. Even if there was a string to test at that point, it would be too late; I have to reconnect. I don't see how I can break it down any further. Additionally, if it actually does return with no message as a null string (rather than waiting) and I handle it successfully, I'll spin in a tight loop and lock a CPU. Shouldn't `ReceiveAsync()` wait for one?

Comment: It would be on the following statement : return message.ToString();  when you don't have an exception handler in the code the Net Library searches up the execution stack for first exception handler.  The place where the exception occurs may have nothing to do with the location of the real issue.  Adding exception handlers or stepping through the code may help find real location of error.

Comment: I did, both add exception handlers and step through the code. Wrapping specifically the `ReceiveAsync()` in a `try` block and stepping into the `catch` to inspect the exception and values of `webSocket` and `cancelToken` is where my question comes from. I also inspected the `Task` output of a `ContinueWith()`. The values change and exception arises at `ReceiveAsync()`

Comment: I would use a sniffer like fiddler to see what is being returned by the server.  It is possible a timeout needs to be increased.  I would check the status returned.  A good status is 200 done.  I would also try with an IE and compare fiddler results to see if same error occurs.  If it works with the IE without error then I would start comparing the http headers to see where the differences occur.  Also clear the IE history between attempts and remove cookies which can effect results.

Comment: @jdweng: WebSockets don't send "200 DONE". They stay open until closed, after "101 UPGRADE". A test from an unmodified browser would would not be successful, and I mentioned the multiple test scenarios I've used in my OP.

Comment: 200 Done is returned after each request/response, not when connection is closed.  Some request get more than one response so each response will have a status (like 100 continue) and the final will have the DONE.  If you aren't getting 200 then something is wrong.  For 101 UPGRADE do you mean http 1.0 vs 1.1?  Http 1.1 supports chunked which doesn't work with the Net Library.  The WebSocket sends http 1.0 in header to server to prevent chunked mode.

Comment: No, for 101 UPGRADE I mean the upgrade from a normal HTTP connection to a WebSockets connection. This is requested immediately in the HTTP GET when setting up a WebSocket, so at no point while the connection is open is a 200 DONE given. HTTP 1.1 is required for WebSockets. Where are you getting your information? "Chunked" is not directly relevant. Read RFC 6455, please.

Comment: I mean no disrespect, but unless I can see we are talking about the same technology, I'm going to stop responding to your suggestions. Also feel free to begin a chat with me.

Comment: The issues i have seen with Http 1.1 is the chunk mode option.  Nobody using the net library has found a solution for chunk mode, so what people revert back to http 1.0.  The issue people have with 1.1 (chunked) is they get only one chunk and cannot get the net library to send additional chunks.  So they get one 100 Continue and never get 200 Done.  This sound the issue you are getting.  Use a sniffer like fiddler to debug your issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112705/discussion-between-jdweng-and-shannon).

Comment: That is very complicated way to create an Observable from a Task... I would use Observable.Create<T>()

Comment: or Observable.Generate, Here is how I used it in one of my projects 
https://github.com/fahadash/ConsoleSharp/blob/master/ConsoleSharp/ObservableMixins.cs#L15

Comment: I t looks like you switch clients class which solved the issue.  WebSocket was using http 1.1 while GetConnectedWebSocket is using html 1.0.  The root cause of issue is you were only getting one response in chunk mode and you were timing out.

Comment: @fahadash: Thank you. However, neither of your suggestions provide the features I need. Your code sample seems to me to have a similar level of complexity; and it neither unwraps a loop of tasks into a continuous observable sequence, nor depends on a resource it automatically disposes, nor waits for an async factory-generated resource before beginning.

Comment: @shannon I have a very similar problem. How did you solve it at the end?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `cancelToken` passed to `ReceiveMessage` function. In Rx implementation before `Task` finish (in your case `Task.FromResult`) cleanup code is executed and as a port if it `cancelToken` is disposed. I had the same problem when I tried to use such code:

```
return Observable.Using(cancelToken => Connect(uri, authToken, cancelToken), (webSocket, token) =>
            Task.FromResult(Observable.Create<string>((observer) => WebSocketReceiver.WebSocketReceiverSubscribe(observer, webSocket, cancelToken))))
            .Publish().RefCount();
```

but this code works:

```
return Observable.Using(cancelToken => Connect(uri, authToken, cancelToken), (webSocket, token) =>
            Task.FromResult(Observable.Create<string>((observer, ct) => WebSocketReceiver.WebSocketReceiverSubscribe(observer, webSocket, ct))))
            .Publish().RefCount();
```

As I can see `Observable.Defer` doesn't pass `CancellationToken` object so you will have to create external one and pass it to `ReceiveMessage`. Alternatively you can play with `Observable.Create` as in my example.